# Код-гольф - Создание генератора кода для печати строк в Brainfuck

Tags: любой-язык, brainfuck, соревнование

Внимание! Соревнование **окончено**! Огромное спасибо всем тем, кто принял в нем участие)
Вы можете ознакомиться с результатами и различными алгоритмами решения поставленной задачи ниже, а если вдруг у Вас возникнет хорошая идея реализации всего этого дела - не стесняйтесь и публикуйте, ведь пусть конкурс уже и закрыт, идеи, предложенные здесь, возможно, впоследствии порадуют одинокого странника `ruSO`, изучающего вопросы по меткам [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) и [соревнование](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5))

---

Товарищи!
Давненько не проходило у нас никаких *соревнований*, так что стоит исправить сие досадное упущение)

---

Думаю, каждый из нас хоть немного знаком с эзотерическим языком [Brainfuck](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) и его в буквальном смысле мозговыносящим синтаксисом. Обычное `Hello world` выглядит страшнее и сложнее [ПО для Аполлона 11](https://github.com/chrislgarry/Apollo-11)...
А почему бы не автоматизировать процесс создания кода на `Brainfuck` для вывода нужных нам строк? Таки вопрос риторический, ибо этим мы и займемся)

---

### Задача:

Требуется описать на любом языке программирования функцию, которая в качестве аргумента принимает *строку*, а на выход дает код на языке `Brainfuck` (также в виде *строки*), позволяющий распечатать входную строку

---

### Подробнее:

Как Вы понимаете, функцию необходимо максимально ужать. Однако это еще не все: роль также будет играть длина выходного кода, так что решение "в лоб" не подойдет)
Вам необходимо будет протестировать свой код на следующих двух строках:

```
s1 = "Hello world"
s2 = "Goodbye Brainfuck"
```

---

### Правила:

1. При решении задачи можно использовать любой язык программирования
2. Можно оставлять несколько вариантов ответа (в **разных** постах)
3. **Запрещено** использовать какие-либо сторонние библиотеки для решения поставленной задачи, если они не являются частью
   используемого языка/платформы
4. **Запрещено** внутри реализуемой функции использовать строки `s1` и `s2` в явном или зашифрованном виде
5. *Желательно* оставлять ссылку на онлайн-компилятор Вашего кода
6. В ответе приводите как минифицированную версию Вашей функции, так и
   "развернутую" (пояснения приветствуются), чтобы каждый мог
   разобраться в магии Вашего кода и, возможно, почерпнуть что-то для
   себя
7. Сгенерированный код на `Brainfuck` должен быть рабочим и выводить
   строки `s1` и `s2` (проверить код можно, скажем, [тут](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/) или [тут](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/))
8. Обязательным условием является наличие у Вашего ответа заголовка в
   формате `<h2>Язык, Кол-воСимволов</h2>` (требуется для парсера
   таблицы лидеров)
9. Рассчет символов определяется следующей **формулой**:
   `N = func.Length + Ceil(1.5 * (B(s1).Length + B(s2).Length))`
   **N** - число символов, которое необходимо указать в ответе
   **func.Length** - длина Вашей минифицированной функции (следует учитывать только длину *тела* функции)
   **B(s1).Length** - длина выходного кода для строки `s1`
   **B(s2).Length** - длина выходного кода для строки `s2`
   **Ceil** - функция округления к ближайшему целому, которое **больше** заданного значения (*Ceil(2.5) == 3*)
10. Продолжительность соревнования: **7 дней**

---

### Определение победителей:

Победители определяются по следующей градации:

1. Реализация с наименьшим числом *символов*
2. Реализация с наивысшим активным *рейтингом* (общее число плюсов -
   общее число минусов)
3. Реализация с самой *ранней* первой редакцией

P.S. - работа автора поста не принимает участия в подведении итогов

---

Если возникнут вопросы по правилам проведения конкурса - задавайте их в комментариях)

---

Удачи в реализации, товарищи!

---

### Итоги:

**1 место:** [@Groxan](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/203662/groxan) - [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/851157) занял *745(!) символов*
**2 место:** [@b1nary](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/30155/b1nary) - [python](/questions/tagged/python), [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852550) занял *827 символов*
**3 место:** [@rjhdby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/210178/rjhdby) - [php](/questions/tagged/php), [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/851106) занял *834 символа*
Собственно, хотелось бы сказать пару слов о прошедшем соревновании)
Еще раз огромное спасибо каждому, кто принял участие в сием мероприятии, ведь, думаю, каждый из нас смог почерпнуть из идей других участников что-то новое и интересное!
Было очень интересно разбирать код, его ужатый вид, а также и логику во всех ответах, каждый из которых по-своему элегантен и интересен)
И отдельно, конечно, хочется сказать про [работу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/851157) [@Groxan](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/203662/groxan), которая заняла всего **745 символов**! Честно, когда я предложил данный эвент, я даже не предполагал, что хоть одна реализация преодолеет барьер в 800 символов. Но это таки случилось. Работа победителя нашего соревнования проделала уверенный путь от 912 символов к победным и действительно удивительным 745 символам!
Почему *"удивительным"*? Предложенный алгоритм смог посоревноваться не только с участниками данного код-гольфа, но и с решением, приведённым на [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) (**111** символов):

> ++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.

Сгенерировав код для строки `Hello World!` (отличается от конкурсной строки `s1`) алгоритмом из ответа-победителя, мы получим ровно те же **111** символов:

> -[------->+<]>-.-[->+++++<]>++.+++++++..+++.+[->--<]>.---[->+++<]>.+[--->--<]>-.+++.------.--------.-[--->+<]>.

Удивительное совпадение)
Очень радует, что наше соревнование и совместные усилия участников смогли создать такой вот замечательный алгоритм!
Так что еще раз отдельное спасибо каждому участнику! До новых соревнований!

---

### Таблица лидеров:

```js
execute(849931);
```

```css
.cssload-container,.cssload-cube{width:97px;height:97px;transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container,.cssload-cube,.cssload-half1,.cssload-half2{transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container{position:relative;margin:23px 84px;perspective:292px}.cssload-cube{animation:cube 11.5s forwards infinite;transform-origin:center 49px}.cssload-half1,.cssload-s1{top:0;transform-origin:50% 100%}.cssload-half1{height:39px;position:absolute;animation:half-fold 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-side{width:19px;height:19px;background:#ddd;position:absolute}.cssload-s1{left:39px;animation:s1ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s2,.cssload-s3,.cssload-s4{left:39px;transform-origin:50% 0}.cssload-s2{top:19px;animation:s2ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s3{top:39px;animation:s3ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s4{top:58px;animation:s4ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s5{left:19px;top:19px;transform-origin:100% 50%;animation:s5ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s6{left:58px;top:39px;transform-origin:0 50%;animation:s6ani 11.5s forwards infinite}@keyframes cube{0%,30%{transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}60%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}65%,70%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(180deg)}75%,80%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(1turn)}90%{transform:rotateX(0) rotate(0) rotate(0)}}@keyframes s1ani{0%{opacity:1;transform:translateY(0);background:#ddd}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(-90deg);background:#ddd}90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}@keyframes s2ani{0%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%,80%{background:#b4b4b4}65%{opacity:1;background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s3ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}20%,90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%{background:#969696}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s4ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%,to{opacity:0}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(90deg);background:#b4b4b4}80%{background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(90deg)}}@keyframes s5ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(-179deg)}20%{opacity:1;background:#ddd;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(90deg)}55%{background:#ddd}60%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{transform:rotateY(90deg);opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s6ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(179deg)}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(-90deg);background:#ddd}60%,80%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(-90deg)}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes half-fold{0%,50%{transform:rotateX(0)}60%,90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}.cssload-container,.cssload-cube{width:97px;height:97px;transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container,.cssload-cube,.cssload-half1,.cssload-half2{transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container{position:relative;margin:23px 84px;perspective:292px}.cssload-cube{animation:cube 11.5s forwards infinite;transform-origin:center 49px}.cssload-half1,.cssload-s1{top:0;transform-origin:50% 100%}.cssload-half1{height:39px;position:absolute;animation:half-fold 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-side{width:19px;height:19px;background:#ddd;position:absolute}.cssload-s1{left:39px;animation:s1ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s2,.cssload-s3,.cssload-s4{left:39px;transform-origin:50% 0}.cssload-s2{top:19px;animation:s2ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s3{top:39px;animation:s3ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s4{top:58px;animation:s4ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s5{left:19px;top:19px;transform-origin:100% 50%;animation:s5ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s6{left:58px;top:39px;transform-origin:0 50%;animation:s6ani 11.5s forwards infinite}@keyframes cube{0%,30%{transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}60%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}65%,70%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(180deg)}75%,80%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(1turn)}90%{transform:rotateX(0) rotate(0) rotate(0)}}@keyframes s1ani{0%{opacity:1;transform:translateY(0);background:#ddd}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(-90deg);background:#ddd}90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}@keyframes s2ani{0%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%,80%{background:#b4b4b4}65%{opacity:1;background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s3ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}20%,90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%{background:#969696}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s4ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%,to{opacity:0}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(90deg);background:#b4b4b4}80%{background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(90deg)}}@keyframes s5ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(-179deg)}20%{opacity:1;background:#ddd;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(90deg)}55%{background:#ddd}60%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{transform:rotateY(90deg);opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s6ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(179deg)}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(-90deg);background:#ddd}60%,80%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(-90deg)}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes half-fold{0%,50%{transform:rotateX(0)}60%,90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}body{font-size: 1rem;line-height: 1.5rem;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;background: #fff;padding: 0 2rem;}h1{font-weight: 600;margin-bottom: 3rem;text-align: center;color: #212121;}#leadership{width: 100%;margin: 1rem auto;border-collapse: collapse;box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);background: #fafafa;}#leadership td{padding: 1rem .5rem !important;text-align: left;font-weight: 500;transition: all .3s ease-in-out;}#leadership tr:hover td{background: #03a9f4;color: #fefefe;}#leadership tr:hover td a{color: #fff;}#leadership th{padding: 1.5rem .5rem !important;color: #727272;text-align: left !important;font-weight: 500;border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;}#leadership a{text-decoration: none;color: #212121;}#leadership a:hover{color: #03a9f4;}#leadership td:nth-of-type(1){text-align: center;color: #727272;font-size: .75rem;}#leadership td:nth-of-type(2){}#leadership td:nth-of-type(2) img{width: 34px;border-radius: 50%;}#leadership th:nth-of-type(5),#leadership th:nth-of-type(6),#leadership th:nth-of-type(7),#leadership td:nth-of-type(5),#leadership td:nth-of-type(6),#leadership td:nth-of-type(7) {text-align: center !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://mayorovp.github.io/codegolf/97314479fcd24a2386e1.js"></script><div class=cssload-container><div class=cssload-cube><div class=cssload-half1><div class="cssload-side cssload-s1"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s2"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s5"></div></div><div class=cssload-half2><div class="cssload-side cssload-s3"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s4"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s6"></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: правило №2 какое то сомнительное. почему бы два разных подхода не реализовать на одном и том же языке?

Comment: @teran хм. Пожалуй, соглашусь с Вами) Просто в предыдущих гольфах порой наблюдал такое правило ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Пожалуйста, не апайте Ваш вопрос! Если вопрос может быть интересен, его поднимет Дух. Возможно.

Comment: @Aid, если имеются ответы с положительным рейтингом, то не поднимет.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, В любом случае апать не нужно. Я у модератора узнавал перед комментарием.

Comment: Вот так нужно апать - без шума в ревизиях))

Comment: Вопрос. Я могу здорово уменьшить код на PHP, функция будет отдавать корректный результат, но при этом будет сыпать адское количество ошибок. Так можно?

Comment: @rjhdby если будет работать - почему нет? В том и суть, чтобы использовать все возможности языка)

Comment: Еще один скользкий момент. В Kotlin, например, я могу сделать так `fun (s:String, l:Char='\u0000')`. Фактически это не будет телом функции, но позволяет выиграть 14 символов на инициализации переменных

Comment: @rjhdby никто не запрещает) Цель и есть - ужать максимально) Да и на деле длина функции, как видите, играет второстепенное значение. Залог успеха - продуманный алгоритм

Comment: *решением, которое на данный момент считается самым оптимальным по длине* – "ходят слухи", что можно уложиться и в 65-70 символов (для хеллоуворлда) :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP увы, нигде не откопал ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ну как же :) https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68494 Не все примеры, правда, у меня оттуда запустились, но вот например `+[++[<+++>->+++<]>+++++++]<<<--.<.<--..<<---.<+++.<+.>>.>+.>.>-.<<<<+.` 70 символов, при этом даже восклицательный знак на конце выведен! Другой вопрос — как написать код генерирующий такое? Я так и не додумался... Хотя идея-то очень хороша, заполнить память в цикле значениями через 3 и потом просто для каждой буквы брать ближайшую по значению ячейку памяти и выводить чуть подкорректировав.

Comment: Или вот, например: `+[>>-->+[<]<+]` ([link](http://inversed.ru/InvMem.htm#InvMem_7)) заполнить память степенями двойки, потом просто складывая нужные получим любую букву, хотя тут, конечно, не факт что в итоге код будет короче. Но идей на самом деле очень много!

Comment: @АндрейNOP таки интересно) Пришлось подредактировать вопрос хД Идей, конечно, много, право жаль, что не все нашли своё отражение в данном мероприятии ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Слишком быстро завершили конкурс, я вот хотел что-нибудь из этого попробовать, но не успел (о награде можно было объявить заранее, но назначить ее позже, например, через неделю после старта)...

Comment: @АндрейNOP на будущее учту, ибо, честно признаться, я не знал, что конкурсные вопросы длятся ровно неделю, я таки и хотел изначально конкурс на 14 дней поставить)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### C#, 745

Функция (334 символа):

```
string w(int k)=>new string(k>0?'+':'-',k>0?k:-k);
int c(int a,int b,int f=0)=>f>255|a%256==0?f:c(a+b,b,++f);
string m(char p,char x){var o=w(x-p);for(int d,n,s=-9;++s<9;)for(d=-9;++d<9;)for(n=-9;++n<9;){var t=w(s)+$"[{w(d)}>{w(n)}<]>"+w(x-c(p+s,d)*n%256);o=t.Length<o.Length?t:o;}return o+".";}
return string.Concat($"\0{v}".Zip(v,m));
```

`Hello world` (97 символов):

> -[------->+<]>-.-[->+++++<]>++.+++++++..+++.+[->--<]>.--[->++++<]>-.--------.+++.------.--------.

`Goodbye Brainfuck` (177 символов):

> -[------->+<]>--.+[->--<]>-..-----------.--.[->----<]>+.--[->+++<]>.--[--->+<]>-.+[->++<]>.[----->---<]>.--[--->--<]>+.++++++++.+++++.--------.-[--->+<]>--.+[->+++<]>+.++++++++.

Чё происходит вообще?

```
string Brainfuck(string text)
{
    //Трансформируем текст в массив разностей и подбираем кротчайший код для каждой
    return string.Concat($"\0{text}".Zip(text, FindBestCode));
}

string FindBestCode(char state, char target)
{
    //Сперва генерируем тупой код
    var code = Fill(target - state);

    //Потом пытаемся подобрать цикл вида 's[d>n<]>r.' так, чтобы он был как можно короче
    //Достаточно перебирать только три параметра, а четвертый вычислять на ходу
    //Вообще, чем шире диапазон перебора, тем лучше точность поиска
    for (int d, n, s = -9; ++s < 9;)
        for (d = -9; ++d < 9;)
            for (n = -9; ++n < 9;)
            {
                //Формируем цикл, попутно вычисляя 'r'
                var cycle = Fill(s)+$"[{Fill(d)}>{Fill(n)}<]>"+Fill(target - (IterationsCnt(state + s, d) * n + 256 * 10) % 256);
                //Если он короче, то запоминаем
                code = cycle.Length < code.Length ? cycle : code;
            }

    return code + ".";
}

int IterationsCnt(int state, int step, int cnt = 0)
{
    //Определяем количество итераций в цикле с шагом 'step', который стартует из 'state'
    //Т.к. цикл может быть бесконечным, добавляем ограничение в 256 итераций
    return cnt > 255 | state % 256 == 0 ? cnt : IterationsCnt(state + step, step, ++cnt);
}

string Fill(int cnt)
{
    //Спамим '+' или '-' в зависимости от знака
    return new string(cnt > 0 ? '+' : '-', cnt > 0 ? cnt : -cnt);
}
```

Comment: @rjhdby Здравый совет! Конечно же я им воспользовался, хотя это и не совсем честно =)

Comment: Ну я в этих ваших шарпах не разбираюсь, мало ли :D

Comment: Правильнее сказать, здесь используется заход через переполнение `byte` =)

Comment: Похоже, что подход "склеим строку в лоб и сархивируем" можно считать исчерпанным. Вряд-ли получится улучшить алгоритм сжатия (только если сам код подужать). Осталось смотреть в сторону параллельности. Будем думать...

Comment: Спасибо! Результат невероятный просто! :)

Comment: `k>0?k:-k` короче чем `Math.Abs(k)`. `int s,d,n` можно внести внутрь первого for.

Comment: Действительно... Спасибо, подправил =)

Comment: Вместо `||` достаточно `|`. `n++` можно из заголовка цикла выбросить и перенести в тело: `w(x+p-c(p+s,d)*n++%256)`. `w(s)+$"[{w(d)}>{w(n)}<]>"+w(x+p-c(p+s,d)*n++%256)` - еще 2 символа

Answer (score 14):

### Brainfuck, 4277

Конечно же в подобных заданиях веселья ради должен найтись <s>идиот</s> сумасшедший, который напишет код на самом `Brainfuck`
Итак, сама функция (74 символа):

```
++++++[>+++++++<-]>+>++++++++[>++++++++<-]>-->,[[<<<.>>>-]<<<+++.--->>.>,]
```

Код для `s1` (1106 символов):

> ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>

Код для `s2` (1696 символов):

> +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>

---

Функция в более читаемом виде:

```
++++++[>+++++++<-]>+        // Записываем код для знака плюс
>
++++++++[>++++++++<-]>--    // Записываем код для знака перехода в следующую ячейку
>
,                           // Считываем символ
[                           // Запускаем цикл зпт который будет идти до символа '\0'
    [<<<.>>>-]              // Печатаем число плюсов зпт необходимое для печати символа
    <<<
    +++.---                 // Увеличиваем код ячейки плюса до точки зпт печатаем и возвращаем
    >>.>                    // Печатаем символ перехода в следующую ячейку
    ,                       // Читаем следующий символ
]
```

**Логика алгоритма:**
Собственно, думаю, логика ясна из пояснений к коду: мы читаем [нуль-терминированную строку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0), для каждого символа выводим кол-во знаков `+`, равное его ASCII-коду, а также символы `.` (для печати) и `>` (для перехода в следующую ячейку)

---

Алгоритм совершенно не оптимален (видно из числа символов хД), зато функция короткая да и написана на языке-герое сего мероприятия)

Answer (score 8):

### С#, 1436

Собственно, сама функция (146 символов):

```
string s(int i)=>new string('+',i);return string.Join("",t.Select(x=>{int a = (int)Math.Sqrt(x);return$"{s(a)}[>{s(x/a)}<-]>{s(x-a*(x/a))}.>";}));
```

Код для `s1` (342 символа):

> ++++++++[>+++++++++<-]>.>++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>+.>++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>++++++++.>++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>++++++++.>++++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>+.>+++++[>++++++<-]>++.>++++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>+++++++++.>++++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>+.>++++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>++++.>++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>++++++++.>++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>.>

Код для `s2` (518 символов):

> ++++++++[>++++++++<-]>+++++++.>++++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>+.>++++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>+.>++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>.>+++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>++++++++.>+++++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>.>++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>+.>+++++[>++++++<-]>++.>++++++++[>++++++++<-]>++.>++++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>++++.>+++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>+++++++.>++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>+++++.>++++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>.>++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>++.>++++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>+++++++.>+++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>.>++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>+++++++.>

---

Функция в более читаемом виде:

```
string s(int i) => new string('+', i);
return string.Join("", t.Select(x => { 
    int a = (int)Math.Sqrt(x);
    return $"{s(a)}[>{s(x/a)}<-]>{s(x-a*(x/a))}.>";
}));
```

**Логика алгоритма:**
Для каждого символа я генерирую цикл на `Brainfuck`, который идет `sqrt(x)` итераций, каждый раз инкрементируя текущую клетку на `x/sqrt(x)`. Так как цикл идет целое число итераций, то после него я инкрементирую текущую ячейку еще на `x-(x/sqrt(x))*sqrt(x)`, тем самым добирая остаток и получая ASCII-код нужного мне символа

---

Посмотреть работу функции можно [тут](https://ideone.com/jsXZg2) (пришлось изменить код, так как online-компиляторы пока не поддерживают новейшие версии `C#`)

Answer (score 8):

### PHP, 834

PHP код (тело 208 символа):

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d489b2ce8dc66bc2ef6e855de9d121d0b7de8b06)

```
for(;$c=ord($s[$i++]);$l=$c){$x=$l<=>$c;$o.=(($r=($t=abs($l-$c))>16?(int)sqrt($t):0)?'>'.str_pad('',$r+1,'+').'[<'.str_pad('',$r,'+ -'[$x+1]).'>-]<':'').str_pad('',abs($t-=$r*$r++),'+ -'[$x*($t<=>0)+1]).'.';}
```

Читабельно(ну...так.)

```
function f ($s, &$o) {
// Перебираем посимвольно. $l - предыдущий ascii код, $c - текущий
    for (; $c = ord($s[$i++]); $l = $c) {
// Направление движения, + или -
        $x = $l <=> $c;
// Адский ад
        $o .= ((
// Вычисляем длину цикла и хвоста
        $r = ($t = abs($l - $c)) > 16
            ? (int)sqrt($t)
            : 0
        )
// Если цикл не нулевой, то отрисовываем его в нужном направлении
            ? '>' . str_pad('', $r+1, '+') . '[<' . str_pad('', $r, '+ -'[$x + 1]) . '>-]<'
            : ''
// Отрисовываем хвост в нужном направлении
          ) . str_pad('', abs($t -= $r * $r++), '+ -'[$x * ($t <=> 0) + 1]) . '.';
    }
}
```

`Hello world` (149 символа):

> >+++++++++[<++++++++>-]<.>++++++[<+++++>-]<-.+++++++..+++.>+++++++++[<-------->-]<-------.>++++++++++[<+++++++++>-]<---.--------.+++.------.--------.

`Goodby Brainfuck` (268 символа):

> >+++++++++[<++++++++>-]<-.>+++++++[<++++++>-]<--..-----------.--.>+++++[<++++>-]<+++.>+++++[<---->-]<.>+++++++++[<-------->-]<+++.>++++++[<+++++>-]<++++.>+++++++[<++++++>-]<++++++.>+++++[<---->-]<+++.++++++++.+++++.--------.+++++++++++++++.>+++++[<---->-]<++.++++++++.

Comment: А где разбор логики алгоритма? Или мы сами должны разбираться? :)

Comment: Luke, use the online Interpreters!

Comment: @Aid Заааануда!

Comment: Yep :).........

Answer (score 7):

### Python, 827

Минифицированный исходник (189 символов)

```
l=0
g="+-"
def f(c):global l;c,l=c-l,c;d=abs(c);z=round(d**.5);D=d-z*z;a='>'+z*'+'+'[<'+z*g[c<0]+'>-]<'+abs(D)*g[D*c<0];d*=g[c<0];return(a,d)[len(a)>len(d)]+'.'
s=''.join(map(f,map(ord,s)))
```

`Hello world` (156 символов).

> >++++++++[<++++++++>-]<++++++++.>+++++[<+++++>-]<++++.+++++++..+++.>+++++++++[<--------->-]<++.>+++++++++[<+++++++++>-]<++++++.--------.+++.------.--------.

`Goodbye Brainfuck` (269 символов).

> >++++++++[<++++++++>-]<+++++++.>++++++[<++++++>-]<++++..-----------.--.>+++++[<+++++>-]<--.>++++[<---->-]<----.>++++++++[<-------->-]<-----.>++++++[<++++++>-]<--.>+++++++[<+++++++>-]<-.>++++[<---->-]<-.++++++++.+++++.--------.+++++++++++++++.>++++[<---->-]<--.++++++++.

#### Итого

189 + 1.5 * (156 + 269) ≈ 827

## Что тут происходит?

Опредлим входную строку как переменную `s`.

```
s = "Hello world"
```

Заметим, что символ для знака числа `N` можно получить из `g[N<0]`.

```
g = "+-"
```

Предусмотрим lookback на один символ в переменной `l`.

```
l = 0
```

Итак, определим ƒ от `c` (кода символа).

```
def f(c):
    global l
```

Далее `c` — разность старого и нового значением, а `d` — расстояние.

```
    c, l = c - l, c
    d = abs(c)
```

Пусть `z` — квадратный корень из расстояния `d`, округленный до ближайшего целого значения.

```
    z = round(d**.5)
```

Строим цикл вида `>z_iterations[<z_operations>-]<`, который прибавляет или вычитает (в зависимости от знака `c`) квадрат числа `z` в ячейке памяти.

```
    a = '>' + z*'+' + '[<' + z*g[c < 0] + '>-]<'
```

Найдем длина хвоста цикла, т.е. разность `D` между расстоянием `d` и квадратом `z` — ровно столько нужно сделать операций "+" или "-" после исполнения цикла.

```
    D = d - z*z
```

Доводим значение в ячейке до желаемого.

```
    a += abs(D) * g[D*c < 0]
```

Однако, вариант без цикла может быть короче.

```
    d *= g[c < 0]
    return (a, d)[len(a) > len(d)] + '.'
```

Применим ƒ для последовательности кодов символов строки `s` и склеим возвращенные значения в одну строку.

```
s = ''.join(map(f, map(ord, s)))
```

Осталось сделать только...

```
print(s, end='')
```

Comment: Я думаю, не стоит учитывать `input` и `print`. Переписал немного ваш код. `def f(c):global l;c,l=c-l,c;d=abs(c);z=round(d**.5);D=d-z*z;a='>'+z*'+'+'[<'+z*g[c<0]+'>-]<'+abs(D)*g[D*c<0];d*=g[c<0];return (a,d)[len(a)>len(d)]+'.'
l=0;g="+-";s=''.join(map(f,map(ord,s)))` **190**

Comment: [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SpanishTwinCache)

Comment: @mkkik, спасибо! Обновил ответ с вашими изменениями.

Answer (score 6):

### С#, 1194

В качестве первого приближения.

Функция (103 символа):

```
string GetBfSrc(string s)
{
    return string.Concat(s.Select((c,i)=>new string("-+"[c>('\0'+s)[i]?1:0],Math.Abs(c-('\0'+s)[i]))+"."));
}
```

`Hello world` (313 символов):

> ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++..+++.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.--------.+++.------.--------.

`Goodbye Brainfuck` (414 символов):

> +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++..-----------.--.+++++++++++++++++++++++.--------------------.---------------------------------------------------------------------.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-----------------.++++++++.+++++.--------.+++++++++++++++.------------------.++++++++.

Comment: А где разбор логики алгоритма? Или мы сами должны разбираться? :)

Comment: @Aid таки правила не оговаривают ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @rjhdby, А 6-ой пункт правил?

Comment: @Aid Приветствуются - не значит обязательны

Comment: @rjhdby, Да и приветствия, вежливость, мораль, долг и другие подобные штуки тоже технически необязательны.

Comment: @Aid вот что точно не обязательно, так это навязывание всем своих представлений о мироустройстве

Comment: @rjhdby, Я их не навязываю, а обращаю внимание что разбор логики даже в правилах рекомендуют сделать.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript 6, 1216

Минифицированная: 613

```
(()=>{var c,v,f,e,h;B=(n)=>{var r,t,u,i,o,f="",e=0,a=[0];for(r in n=c(n))o=(t=n[r])-a[e],u=[v(o,e),v(o+256,e),v(o-256,e),">"+v(t,e+1),">"+v(t-256,e+1)],2<(i=h(u))&&e++,a[e]=t,f+=u[i]+".";return f},c=(n)=>{var r;for(r in n=n.split(""))n[r]=n[r].charCodeAt(0);return n},v=(n,r)=>{if(29999<r)return f("#",256);var t,u,i,o=+(n<0);return o&&(n=-n),i=f(o="+-"[o],n),15<n&&r<29999&&(t=0|Math.sqrt(n),u=">"+v(n/t|0,r+1)+"[<"+f(o,t)+">-]<"+f(o,n%t),e(u)<e(i))?u:i},f=(n,r)=>{var t=[];return t.length=r+1,t.join(n)},e=(n)=>{return n.length},h=(n)=>{var r,t=(n=n.map(e))[0],u=0;for(r in n)n[r]<t&&(t=n[r],u=r);return u}})();
```

`Hello world`: 143

> >+++++++++[<++++++++>-]<.>+++++[<+++++>-]<++++.+++++++..+++.>>++++++[<+++++>-]<++.>+++++++++[<+++++++++>-]<++++++.--------.+++.------.--------.

`Goodbye Brainfuck`: 259

> >++++++++[<++++++++>-]<+++++++.>++++++[<++++++>-]<++++..-----------.--.>+++++[<++++>-]<+++.>+++++[<---->-]<.>>++++++[<+++++>-]<++.>++++++[<+++++>-]<++++.>++++++++[<++++++>-]<.>++++[<---->-]<-.++++++++.+++++.--------.+++++++++++++++.>++++[<---->-]<--.++++++++.

#### Исходный код:

```
(function(){
    var s2a, Ba, rep, L, shortest, G = '+-', M = 29999;
    B = function(s) {
        var C = '', i, c, v, vi, d, bi = 0, U = [0];
        s = s2a(s); //s в массив чисел
        for(i in s) {
            c = s[i];
            d = c - U[bi];
            v = [Ba(d, bi), Ba(d + 256, bi), Ba(d - 256, bi), '>' + Ba(c, bi + 1), '>' + Ba(c - 256, bi + 1)]; //Несколько вариантов получения нужного числа
            vi = shortest(v); //Индекс наиболее короткого
            if(vi > 2) {
                bi++; //Сдвигаем указатель текущего положения
            }
            U[bi] = c;
            C += v[vi] + '.'; //Сохранение кода
        }
        return C;
    }
    s2a = function(s) {
        var i;
        s = s.split('');
        for(i in s) s[i] = s[i].charCodeAt(0);
        return s;
    }
    Ba = function(d, bi) { //Эффективный код прибавления разности d в ячейке bi
        if(bi > M) return rep('#', 256); //Переполнение массива, выдаём очень длинный код
        var s = +(d < 0), r, R, C, D;
        if(s) d = -d; //d = abs(d)
        s = G[s]; //Знак разности
        D = rep(s, d); //Код без цикла
        if(d > 15 && bi < M) { //Когда разность < 15, цикл не выгоден; проверка на переполнение
            r = Math.sqrt(d) | 0; //r = int(sqrt(d))
            R = (d / r) | 0;
            C = '>' + Ba(R, bi + 1) + '[<' + rep(s, r) + '>-]<' + rep(s, d % r);
            if(L(C) < L(D)) {
                return C; //Если с циклом выгоднее, возвращаем его
            }
        }
        return D;
    }
    rep = function(s, n) { //Повторенние строки s n раз
        var a = [];
        a.length = n + 1;
        return a.join(s);
    }
    L = function(a) { //Длинна массива/строки
        return a.length;    
    }
    shortest = function(v) { //Индекс наиболее короткого
        v = v.map(L);
        var m = v[0], mi = 0, i;
        for(i in v) {
            if(v[i] < m) {
                m = v[i];
                mi = i;
            }
        }
        return mi;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

### C, 898

Минифицированный (238)

```
#define A*(K++)=
int O[999],*K=O,p=0;F(n,c){while(n--)A c;}M(a){if(a<0)F(-a,45);else F(a,43);}P(c){int d=c-p;if(d*d<225)M(d);else{A'>';M(8);A'[';A'<';M(d/8);A'>';A'-';A']';A'<';M(d%8);}A'.';p=c;}*B(int*s){while(*s)P(*(s++));A 0;return O;}
```

`Hello world` (156)

> >++++++++[<+++++++++>-]<.>++++++++[<+++>-]<+++++.+++++++..+++.>++++++++[<--------->-]<-------.>++++++++[<++++++++++>-]<+++++++.--------.+++.------.--------.

`Goodbye Brainfuck` (284)

> >++++++++[<++++++++>-]<+++++++.>++++++++[<+++++>-]<..-----------.--.>++++++++[<++>-]<+++++++.>++++++++[<-->-]<----.>++++++++[<-------->-]<-----.>++++++++[<++++>-]<++.>++++++++[<++++++>-]<.>++++++++[<-->-]<-.++++++++.+++++.--------.>++++++++[<+>-]<+++++++.>++++++++[<-->-]<--.++++++++.

#### Код с пояснениями

```
int codeOutput[999], *codeEnd = codeOutput, p = 0;
int repeatChar(int n, int c) {
    while(n--) *(codeEnd++) = c; // Пишет n раз символ c
}
int modifyValue(int a) { //Пишет код, изменяющий значение в текущей ячейке
    if(a < 0) {
        repeatChar(-a, '-');
    } else {
        repeatChar(a, '+');
    }
}
int proceedChar(int c) { //Обработать символ исходной строки
    int d = c;
    d -= p; //Разность с предыдущим значением в ячейке
    if(d*d < 225) { //Если abs(d) < 15
        modifyValue(d); //Тогда предполагается, что выгоднее менять значение без цикла
    } else {
        *(codeEnd++) = '>'; //Запись в bf код сдвига ячейки
        modifyValue(8); //Счётчик цикла. разность d преобразуется в 8 * a + b
        *(codeEnd++) = '[';
        *(codeEnd++) = '<';
        modifyValue(d / 8); //В цикле прибавляем (вычитаем) целую часть от деления
        *(codeEnd++) = '>';
        *(codeEnd++) = '-';
        *(codeEnd++) = ']';
        *(codeEnd++) = '<';
        modifyValue(d % 8); //Прибавляем остаток
    }
    *(codeEnd++) = '.';
    p = c; //Запоминаем текущее значение в ячейке
    return 0;
}
int *B(int *s) { //Главная функция
    while(*s != '\0') {
        proceedChar(*(s++));
    }
    *(codeEnd++) = '\0';
    return codeOutput;
}

#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("%ls", B(L"Hello world"));
}
```

Comment: Можно убрать `#define V void` и использовать везде возвращаемое значение, например `I`

Comment: Не забудьте привести и развёрнутую версию вашей функции, дабы другие могли понять алгоритм ее работы хоть не из Ваших пояснений, а из самого кода

Comment: Приведенный результат не соответствует результату приведенного кода

Comment: @Groxan да, я тоже только что заметил.  Но это не проблема, я переписал код на https://repl.it/repls/OrchidShallowJavabeans — так хоть по размеру исходника соответсвует рез-ту по формуле.

Comment: 252 + 1.5*(204 + 322) ≈ 1041

Comment: Если что, то моя версия на C89.  Так короче, но repl.it кидает кучу ворнингов, ибо использует другой стандарт.  `clang` и `gcc` с флагом `-std=c89` почти не ругаются.

Comment: $ gcc --version
clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)                                                                     Target: aarch64--linux-android                                                                                   Thread model: posix                                                                                              InstalledDir: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin

Comment: В функции `repeatChar` можно заменить `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` на `while(n--)`. Также `int d=c;d-=p;` - то же самое, что и `int d=c-p;`

Comment: @Groxan c, p - char. Разве там можно получить отрицательную разность?

Comment: @vftdan можно =) И еще, `#define V void` и `#define I int` можно убрать, т.к. они лишь увеличивают код

Comment: @Groxan признаю ошибку, спутал с byte в C#, который по умолчанию unsigned

Comment: `*(s++)`: должно работать без скобок

Answer (score 3):

### JS, 1067

Тело функции (446 символов):

```
var u=n=>Math.round(n);var p=n=>n>0?n:-n;var g=c=>(c>0?"+":"-").repeat(p(c));var d=c=>c.charCodeAt(0);var r=f=>(f?">":"<").repeat(l+2);var h=[0,0];var l=0;s=s.split("");s.forEach((e,i,a)=>{var j="";var k=d(e);var m=p(k-h[1])<p(k-h[0])?1:0;if (m!=l){j+=m>l?">":"<";l=m;}var o=k-h[m];var y=u(Math.sqrt(p(o)));var z=u(o/y);var q=g(o);var t=r(1)+g(y)+"["+r()+g(z)+r(1)+"-]"+r()+g(o-y*z);a[i]=j+(t.length<q.length?t:q)+".";h[m]=k;});return s.join("");
```

Код для `s1` (135 символов):

> ++++++++[<<+++++++++>>-]<<.>>+++++[<<++++++>>-]<<-.+++++++..+++.>>>>++++++[<<<+++++>>>-]<<<++.<++++++++.--------.+++.------.--------.

Код для `s2` (279 символов):

> ++++++++[<<+++++++++>>-]<<-.>>++++++[<<+++++++>>-]<<--..-----------.--.+++++++++++++++++++++++.--------------------.>>>>++++++[<<<+++++>>>-]<<<++.>>>++++++[<<<++++++>>>-]<<<--.<+++++++++++++.-----------------.++++++++.+++++.--------.+++++++++++++++.------------------.++++++++.

---

Функция в развернутом виде:

```js
function Brainfuck(s) {
// Генерация последовательности из '+' или '-'
var gen = count => (count > 0 ? "+" : "-").repeat(Math.abs(count));
// Получение кода символа
var code = c => c.charCodeAt(0);
// Получение пути к ячейке, хранящей счетчик цикла
var getCell = forward => (forward ? ">" : "<").repeat(currentCell + state.length);
// Состояние двух используемых для печати ячеек
var state = [0, 0];
// Текущая ячейка
var currentCell = 0;
// Массив символов
var chars = s.split("");
// Обрабатываем все символы
chars.forEach((element, index, arr) => {
    var answer = "";
    var now = code(element);
    // Выбираем наиболее выгодную ячейку и рассчитываем необходимые изменения ячейки
    var cell = 0;     
    var need =  Math.abs(now - state[0]);  
    for (var i = 1; i < state.length; i++) {
        var newNeed = Math.abs(now - state[i]);
        if (newNeed < need) {
            need = newNeed;
            cell = i;
        }
    }
    need = now - state[cell];
    // Сдвигаемся, если выгодная ячейка отличается от текущей
    if (cell != currentCell) {
        answer += (cell > currentCell ? ">" : "<").repeat(Math.abs(cell - currentCell));
        currentCell = cell;
    }
    // Генерируем последовательность из '+' или '-' без всяких циклов
    var genned = gen(need);
    var a = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.abs(need)));
    var b = Math.round(need / a);   
    // Генерируем равнозначную по выполнению genned команду, но с циклом
    var test = getCell(true) + gen(a) + "[" + getCell(false) + gen(b) + getCell(true) + "-]" + getCell(false) + gen(need - a*b);
    // Выбираем самое короткое решение
    genned = test.length < genned.length ? test : genned;
    answer += genned;
    // Добавляем символ печати и обновляем текущий элемент массива
    arr[index] = answer + ".";
    // Изменяем состояние текущей ячейки
    state[cell] = now;
});
// Возвращаем объединенный массив
return chars.join("");
}

console.log(Brainfuck("Hello world"));
console.log();
console.log(Brainfuck("Goodbye Brainfuck"));
```

---

#### Идея:

Мы используем 3 ячейки памяти, отводя *первые 2* для хранения кода символов, а *последнюю* - для счетчика цикла `Brainfuck`. Тем самым на каждом шаге мы выбираем ту ячейку, которая должна претерпеть минимальные изменения для получения кода текущего символа.
В теории, с ростом числа используемых ячеек (до некого абстрактного максимума, который необходимо подобрать эмпирически) на больших текстах можно получить хороший выигрыш по длине генерируемого кода. Расширить число ячеек в принципе просто, так что если кто захочет с этим поиграться - прошу (достаточно просто увеличить число элементов в массиве `state`))
**P.S.** - минифицированная функция немного отличается от развернутой, так как в минифицированной я ориентируюсь на ровно 2 ячейки (что является оптимальным решением для указанных строк)

Answer (score 2):

### 05AB1E, 709

Жаль, соревнование уже кончилось

Код 80 символов, 96 UTF-8 байт:

```
0IÇDdgi)}v'+sys-D0‹i(s\'-s}D15s‹i'>?DtóD'+s.×J?„[<?‰`sŠŠDŠs.×J?">-]<"?s}.×J?'.?y
```

[Интерпретатор](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fwPNwu0tKeqZmbZm6dnFlsa6LwaOGnZkaxTHqusW1LoamxSCuup29S8nhzS5AJXqHp3vZP2qYF20DJDckFB9dcHSBy9EFEHElO91YGyX74lowT13PvvL/f4/UnJx8hfL8opwUAA)

`Hello world` 153:

> >++++++++[<+++++++++>-]<.>+++++[<+++++>-]<++++.+++++++..+++.>++++++++[<--------->-]<-------.>+++++++++[<+++++++++>-]<++++++.--------.+++.------.--------.

`Goodbye Brainfuck` 266:

> >++++++++[<++++++++>-]<+++++++.>++++++[<++++++>-]<++++..-----------.--.>++++[<+++++>-]<+++.>++++[<----->-]<.>++++++++[<-------->-]<-----.>+++++[<++++++>-]<++++.>++++++[<++++++++>-]<.>++++[<---->-]<-.++++++++.+++++.--------.+++++++++++++++.>++++[<---->-]<--.++++++++.

#### Пояснение

Алгоритм является упрощённой версией моего алгоритма на JS6 (без переполнения char и без перехода в следующую ячейку, если выгоднее начать с нуля)

#### Условные обозначения:

y - код текущего символа

p - код предыдущего символа

d' = y - p (на сколько изменить код символа)

d = abs(d')

s = char(sign(d'))

a, b -> b, a - поменять местами верхние два элемента на стеке

a, b, c -> c, a, b - циклический сдвиг верхних трёх элементов (вставить верхний под a)

write(s) = print(s, end = "")

#### Сам код:

```
0   push(p = 0)
I   push(input())
Ç   push(pop().map(charToInt))
Ddgi)}  Если введён ровно 1 символ, вместо массива будет число => оборачиваем в массив
v   for y in pop():
'+s push(s = "+"); p, s -> s, p
ys- push(y); p, y -> y, p; push(d' = (-pop(p) + pop(y)))
D0‹ push(peek(d')); push(0); push(pop(0) > pop(d'))
i(s\'-s}    if(pop(d' < 0)) {push(d = -pop(d')); s, d -> d, s; pop(s = "+"); push(s = "-"); d, s -> s, d}
D15s‹i  if(peek(d) > 15): (см. комментарий к JS коду)
'>? write(">")
Dtó push(fsd = floor(sqrt(peek(d))))
D'+s    push("+", peek(fsd))
.×J?    write(int(pop(fsd)) * str(pop("+")))
„[<?    write("[<")
‰`  push(*[d // fsd, d % fsd])
sŠŠDŠ   s, (d // fsd), (d % fsd) -> (d % fsd), s, (d // fsd), s
s.×J?   write(str(pop(s)) * int(pop(d // fsd)))
">-]<"? write(">-]<")
s   (d % fsd), s -> s, (d % fsd)
}   end if
.×J?    write(int(pop((d % fsd) if d > 15 else d)) * str(pop(s)))
'.?y    write("."); push(p = y)
```

Comment: Очень интересное решение) Опишете сам алгоритм для будущих поколений?)