# Вернуть первый не повторяющийся символ из строки, есть ли решение получше?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Например, для строки `abacabad` результат будет `c` хоть и есть еще не повторяющийся символ `d`, но он после `c`.

Если нет такого символа, то вернуть null. Пример: `bcccccccb`, результат: `null`.

Мое решение:

```
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter (s) {
    let o = {}
    for (let l of s)
        o[l] = !o.hasOwnProperty(l)
    for (k in o)
        if (o[k]) return k
    return null
}
```

Comment: а как же пример собственных попыток решить задачу?

Comment: у меня есть мое решение, так важно его дать? Думал лучше если будете исходить только из своих мыслей, не смотреть как я сделал и делать по похожему.

Comment: здесь не проводятся конкурсы

Comment: Ладно, дайте критику моему решению, а то я не уверен что сделал идеально коротко и понятно

Comment: @Sublihim конкурсы здесь проводятся, вот пример [последнего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849931/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-brainfuck)

Comment: @Anamnian не видел. Но, видимо, в таком случае они и оформлены должны быть соотвественно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если поддерживается ES2018, то можно так:

```js
function check(s) {
  var match = s.match(/(.)(?!.*\1)(?<!\1.+)/)
  return match && match[1]
}

console.log(check("abacabad"))
console.log(check("bcccccccb"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Тоже интересный вариант, до этого и не использовал `lastIndexOf`

```js
function check (s) {
  for (let l of s)
    if (s.indexOf(l) === s.lastIndexOf(l))
      return l
  return null
}

console.log(check("abacabad"))
console.log(check("bcccccccb"))
```